# Material Js Md-dialog appears outside of the screen after IPad Mobile Keyboard is used

Tags: angularjs, ipad, mobile, angular-material, mddialog

I encountered this specific issue with Material's md-dialog:

1. I click on any of the text boxes on the web page, which brings up
   the mobile keyboard, this is on IPad 9.3.2.
2. after typing, I then either minimise the keyboard or leave it on
3. and click a button which shows a md-dialog as modal.
4. the modal shows up, which grays out and blocks the whole page.
   but the dialog box appears outside of the screen, i.e. you cant see
   it, you cant touch it, you cant close it.

now if I til the screen to change the orientation from horizontal to vertical or vise-versa, the screen resizes and the dialog is shown properly.

so as soon as i use the keyboard the immediate dialog show will be located incorrectly.

I am wondering if any one had this problem before, and if you know how to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by wrapping it in a timeout:

```
var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
              .title('Test')
              .content('This is test content')
              .ariaLabel('Test')
              .ok('Got it!')
              .cancel('Cancel');

$timeout(
    $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
        // Do Something
    })
, 0);
```